# How to list all PNG images in a sub directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Let `sub dir` be my sub directory in which many images of various format exist.

I tried the following but the output contains not only PNG but also other formats.

```
cmd /c dir /b "sub dir" *.png > output.txt
```

My question is what is the correct syntax to list all PNG images in `sub dir`?

Note that I invoked the code above via `\immediate\write18{...}` (TeX macro to invoke an external file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd /c dir /b "sub dir\*.png" > output.txt
```

should work for you.